# How to prune a Detectron2 model?

Tags: computer-vision, pytorch, web-deployment, object-detection, faster-rcnn

I'm a teacher who is studying computer vision for months. I was very excited when I was able to train my first object detection model using Detectron2's Faster R-CNN model. And it works like a charm! Super cool!

But the problem is that, in order to increase the accuracy, I used [the largest model](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/master/configs/COCO-Detection/faster_rcnn_X_101_32x8d_FPN_3x.yaml) in the model zoo.

Now I want to deploy this as something people can use to ease their job. But, the model is so large that it takes ~10 seconds to infer a single image on my CPU which is Intel i7-8750h.

Therefore, it's really difficult to deploy this model even on a regular cloud server. I need to use either GPU servers or latest model CPU servers which are really expensive and I'm not sure if I can even compensate for server expenses for months.

I need to make it smaller and faster for deployment.

So, yesterday I found that there's something like pruning the model!! I was very excited (since I'm not a computer or data scientists, don't blame me (((: )

I read [official pruning documentation of PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/pruning_tutorial.html), but it's really difficult for me to understand.

I found global pruning is of the easiest one to do. [image]

But the problem is, I have no idea what parameters should I write to prune.

Like I said, I used Faster R-CNN X-101 model. I have it as "**model_final.pth**". And it uses [Base RCNN FPN.yaml](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/master/configs/Base-RCNN-FPN.yaml) and its meta architecture is "GeneralizedRCNN".

It seems like an easy configuration to do. But like I said, since it's not my field it's very hard for a person like me.

I'd be more than happy if you could help me on this step by step.

I'm leaving my cfg.yaml which I used training the model and I saved it using ["dump"](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/modules/config.html#detectron2.config.CfgNode.dump) method in Detectron2 config class just in case. Here's the [Drive link.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H1fAYxRuCFK6LmSYq6lmT4kk8vBJ8vai/view?usp=sharing)

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I guess, you are trying to optimize inference time and achieving satisfactory accuracy. Without knowing details about your object types, training size, image size, it will be hard to provide suggestions. However, as you know, ML project development is an iterative process, you can have a look at the following page and check inference and accuracy.

https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/master/MODEL_ZOO.md#coco-object-detection-baselines

I would suggest, you try R50-FPN backbone and see how your accuracy comes. Then, you will get a better understanding of what to do next.

Comment: Thank you, I've trained R50-FPN x3 model and its accuracy is nearly same and it's way faster. I'll probably use this model.

Comment: Also, the large model was more for research purposes, rather than deploying. https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/issues/1997#issuecomment-686667346

Comment: you can also use a large model for Data Distillation - https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.04440

Comment: if you need to speed up further, then you can use an even shallower backbone, like Resnet34.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to deploy on mobile platforms/edge deployments. You can try the recently released D2go software systems.

It is a deep learning toolkit powered by PyTorch and Detectron2. With a state-of-the-art efficient backbone networks for mobile devices. End-to-end model training, quantization and deployment pipeline. Easy export to TorchScript format for deployment.

https://github.com/facebookresearch/d2go/